# RxSwift and MVVM: observable not executing without binding

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and trying implement app that using MVVM architecture. I have view model:

```
class CategoriesViewModel {

fileprivate let api: APIService
fileprivate let database: DatabaseService

let categories: Results<Category>

// Input
let actionRequest = PublishSubject<Void>()

// Output
let changeset: Observable<(AnyRealmCollection<Category>, RealmChangeset?)>
let apiSuccess: Observable<Void>
let apiFailure: Observable<Error>

init(api: APIService, database: DatabaseService) {
    self.api = api
    self.database = database

    categories = database.realm.objects(Category.self).sorted(byKeyPath: Category.KeyPath.name)

    changeset = Observable.changeset(from: categories)

    let requestResult = actionRequest
        .flatMapLatest { [weak api] _ -> Observable<Event<[Category]>> in
            guard let strongAPI = api else {
                return Observable.empty()
            }

            let request = APIService.MappableRequest(Category.self, resource: .categories)
            return strongAPI.mappedArrayObservable(from: request).materialize()
        }
        .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

    apiSuccess = requestResult
        .map { $0.element }
        .filterNil()
        .flatMapLatest { [weak database] newObjects -> Observable<Void> in
            guard let strongDatabase = database else {
                return Observable.empty()
            }

            return strongDatabase.updateObservable(with: newObjects)
        }

    apiFailure = requestResult
        .map { $0.error }
        .filterNil()
}

}
```

and I have following binginds in view controller:

```
   viewModel.apiSuccess
        .map { _ in false }
        .bind(to: refreshControl.rx.isRefreshing)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    viewModel.apiFailure
        .map { _ in false }
        .bind(to: refreshControl.rx.isRefreshing)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But if I comment bindings, part with database updating stops executing. I need to make it execute anyway, without using dispose bag in the view model. Is it possible?

And little additional question: should I use weak-strong dance with `api`/`database` and `return Observable.empty()` like in my view model code or can I just use `unowned api`/`unowned database` safely?

Thanks.

UPD:

Function for return observable in APIService:

```
func mappedArrayObservable<T>(from request: MappableRequest<T>) -> Observable<[T]> {
    let jsonArray = SessionManager.jsonArrayObservable(with: request.urlRequest, isSecured: request.isSecured)
    return jsonArray.mapResponse(on: mappingSheduler, { Mapper<T>().mapArray(JSONArray: $0) })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work doesn't get done unless there is a subscriber prepared to receive the results.

Your DatabaseService needs to have a dispose bag in it and subscribe to the `Observable<[Category]>`. Something like:

```
class ProductionDatabase: DatabaseService {

    var categoriesUpdated: Observable<Void> { return _categories }

    func updateObservable(with categories: Observable<[Category]>) {
        categories
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] categories in
                // store categories an then
                self?._categories.onNext()
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    private let _categories = PublishSubject<Void>()
    private let bag = DisposeBag()
}
```

Then `apiSuccess = database.categoriesUpdated` and `database.updateObservable(with: requestResult.map { $0.element }.filterNil())`

Comment: Thanks! But can I use `unowned self` instead `[weak self]` on subscribe? It seems like subscribe with `disposeBag` owned by `self` can't be called after `self` deinitialization, but I'm not sure. Or can subscribe block starts executing, do save work at background, and reach `self?._categories.onNext()` after `self` gets deallocated?

Comment: Only use `unowned` if you know that self will exist for the life of the program, you know that the subscribe will only be called once, or the subscribe closure is doing something that will cause `self` to be deleted, otherwise use `weak`. BTW, you can also do the above with your `APIService`, then your view model will only contain logic.

Comment: Do you mean I should subscribe to `actionRequest` in api service and return objects from underlying subject, like in database example? But I have generic function to return observable (see in updated answer) and it's not clear for me how it will work if I will do two requests with different return type from same instance of `APIService`

Comment: It will work if pass `PublishSubject` instance into service method with observable and call `onNext(:_)` on it instead of using property like `private let _categories = PublishSubject<Void>()`. So the compiler will infer return type and every subscription will have own subject to notify.

Comment: The point I'm making is that you only mention one input to your model, but you also have inputs from your api service and database. It would be helpful to model those as first class inputs instead of burying them inside flatMaps. How (or if) you want to do that is up to you.